# Create a custom pattern in the Latex package "tikz"

Tags: latex, tikz

I am working with "tikz" presently and found out is is possible to to fill areas with certain patterns, see p. 217 on https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

Now my question is: Is it possible to implement custom patterns? For example, i need to fill an area with the hatching of concrete, as you can see here: http://www.sema-soft.com/de/forum/files/schraff_886.jpg

Anyone of you tried that before?

Thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIK, creating or modifying patterns require to program at the pgflevel. But the best would be to ask for help at tex.stackexchange.com By the way, your tikz doc is terribly outdated. It is for tikz1.18, while present version is 3.01. Present doc is 1000+ pages instead of 400.  Maybe you should upgrade.

Comment: Updated [**PGF Manual**](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).